# Format date in ActiveAdmin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I got a list of trips which I display in ActiveAdmin, the index uses a formats.fr.yml and the date is displayed with the right format. 
However, when I modify a trip, in the form, ActiveAdmin doesn't use formats.fr.yml anymore. 
Here is the line in the form :

```
f.input :start_date, as: :date_time_picker
```

I tried something like this :

```
f.input :start_date, as: :date_time_picker, :value => :start_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %I:%M')
```

But it doesn't work.
By the way, when I change the date with the datepicker, it changes the date to the right format (but because of some js).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
f.input :start_date, :value => :start_date.try(:strftime,'%y-%m-%d %i:%m')
```

Where `try` will prevent you from getting exceptions, when date is nil.